# Use a var from one method into a different one

Tags: c#, list, methods, void

For school I need to create a program that shuffles and divides a deck of cards.

I want to get a variable from one method(void) to be returned. But because it's inside a Void it can't. But if I create it outside the Void then it gives an error. Because it is a var. I made a list from that var.
I am kinda new to C#. Help would be really appreciated.

```
public static class Kaart
{
    public static void Kaarten() {
        string s = "";
        string v = "";
        string k = "";
        string kaart = "";

        var deck = new List<string>();

        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            switch (x)
            {
                case 0: s = "Harten"; break;
                case 1: s = "Klaver"; break;
                case 2: s = "Schoppen"; break;
                case 3: s = "Ruiten"; break;
            }

            for (int y = 0; y < 13; y++)
            {
                switch (y)
                {
                    case 0: v = "A"; break;
                    case 1: v = "2"; break;
                    case 2: v = "3"; break;
                    case 3: v = "4"; break;
                    case 4: v = "5"; break;
                    case 5: v = "6"; break;
                    case 6: v = "7"; break;
                    case 7: v = "8"; break;
                    case 8: v = "9"; break;
                    case 9: v = "10"; break;
                    case 10: v = "Boer"; break;
                    case 11: v = "Koningin"; break;
                    case 12: v = "Koning"; break;
                }
                kaart = k + " " + s + " " + v;
                deck.Add(kaart);
            }
            Shuffle(deck);
        }
    }

    public static Shuffle(List<string> deck)
    {
        Random rng = new Random();
        //Shuffled het deck;
        var shuffledDeck = deck.OrderBy(a => rng.Next()).ToList();
        return shuffledDeck;

    }
}
```

With this code Shuffle will give an error that he does not have a return. I really don't know what to do anymore

Comment: Because your `Shuffle`method does not have a return type. You are returning a List so the method signature should be `public static List<string> Shuffle(...)`

Comment: You're indeed right. This is the solution to that problem! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your `Shuffle` method like so:

```
public static Shuffle(List<string> deck)
```

In C#, methods need to have a return type that goes before the method name. Change the declaration to this:

```
public static List<string> Shuffle(List<string> deck)
```

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, you might want to create a simple class representing a `Card`:

```cs
public class Card
{
    public Card(int color, int val)
    {
        Color = color;
        Value = val;
    }
    public int Color { get; }
    public int Value { get; }

    // That might look nicer in the debugger (with less code).
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "♥♣♦♠"[Color] + "A23456789TNQK"[Value];
    }
}
```

And I'm not sure, if you course is also (a bit) about Object Orientation, but you might then want to implement the static method `Card.GetDeck()` returning a list (or array) of cards.